# Updating the page creation code in WordPress (get_page_by_title() deprecated)

Tags: php, wordpress

I use the following code to create the page after installing my theme.

```
$check_page_exist = get_page_by_title ('test', 'OBJECT', 'page'); 
if(empty($check_page_exist)) {
   $page_id = wp_insert_post(
       array(
       'comment_status' => 'close',          
       'ping_status'    => 'close',        
       'post_author'    => 1,           
       'post_title'     => ucwords('test'),    
       'post_name'      => strtolower(str_replace(' ', '-', trim('test'))),     
       'post_status'    => 'publish',        
       'post_content'   => ' ',             
       'post_type'      => 'page',       
       'post_parent'    => ' '           
       )
   );
}
```

This code works correctly and generates the pages I need.

The only problem this code has is related to the `get_page_by_title()` part. After installing and running the Query Monitor plugin, it gives me a message that this item is obsolete.

In the previous question, I was sent a page address that still did not solve my problem.

The address of the page related to the `get_page_by_title() deprecated` error:

[make.wordpress.org/core/2023/03/06/get_page_by_title-deprecated](https://make.wordpress.org/core/2023/03/06/get_page_by_title-deprecated)

Please, if possible, edit my code so that this message is no longer displayed to me and it creates the page I want as before.

Many thanks.

---

**Edit code:**

```
$check_page_exist = new WP_Query( array(
  'pagename'       => 'test',
  'posts_per_page' => 1,
  'no_found_rows'  => true,
  'fields'         => 'ids',
) );

if ( empty( $check_page_exist->posts ) ) { 
     $page_id = wp_insert_post(
       array(
       'comment_status' => 'close',          
       'ping_status'    => 'close',        
       'post_author'    => 1,           
       'post_title'     => ucwords('test'),    
       'post_name'      => strtolower(str_replace(' ', '-', trim('link'))), // I have changed my desired link for this page   
       'post_status'    => 'publish',        
       'post_content'   => '',             
       'post_type'      => 'page',       
       'post_parent'    => ' '           
       )
   );
}
```

Comment: Hello. Sorry, I forgot to copy the code.

Comment: in the link you provided, it mentions alternatives to `get_page_by_title`

Comment: Yes. But when I edit the code as mentioned, no page is generated. I don't know, maybe I'm wrong. If possible, edit my code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Documentation for `get_page_by_title()`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/get_page_by_title/) suggests using `WP_Query` as replacement.

Untested code:

```php
$check_page_exist = new WP_Query( array(
    'pagename'       => 'test',
    'posts_per_page' => 1,
    'no_found_rows'  => true,
    'fields'         => 'ids',
) );

if ( empty( $check_page_exist->posts ) ) {
    // Create your page.
}
```

Comment: Hello. I tried your code (edit code). Previously it wouldn't generate any page for me but with your code it generates a page every second and won't stop until I remove the code.

Comment: Hmm, I copied your code into a WordPress install, and it generated only one _Test_ page. Where are you running the code?

Comment: I had not copied the code correctly. If I use the word (test) in all three cases, there is no problem, but when I change the page link, this problem occurs. Is there a way to solve this problem? I edited the code again.

Comment: You'll need to change the `pagename` parameter in the `WP_Query` args to match whatever the slug of the created page is.

Comment: I tried this too. The answer was the same as before and a duplicate page was constantly created. I just want a page to be created for me with a different page title and page link. Please, if it is possible, edit the code that I brought in editing my question so that I have a page with the name (`test`) and URL (`link`).

Comment: Change `'pagename' => 'test',` to `'pagename' => 'link',`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/253955/discussion-between-caleb-and-php).

Comment: I realized my mistake. Thank you very much for your time.